# How to prevent WCF service to register non 127.0.0.1 adresses?

Tags: wcf, localhost

When registering a WCF Service I get

```
HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/ because TCP port 8080 is being used by another application
```

Looking at the used ports with

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

I can see that TCP 127.0.0.2:8080 is used (I'm using ssh to tunnel from 127.0.0.2:8080 to a remote service).

Probably the WCF service tries not only to register at 127.0.0.1 and the network ips but also on 127.0.0.2.

How can I configure the WCF service to not try to listen to 127.0.0.2:8080 but only to 127.0.0.1:8080 and the network ip adresses? Or can I configure the init process that adresses where the service can not be registered are just ignored?

Answer (score 0):

whole 127/8 block signifies localhost. so both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 point to local machine. which implies 127.0.0.1:8080 is same as specifying 127.0.0.2:8080.

they both point to same service which in this case is ssh tunnel . hence WCF fails to register

solution is to change port number.

Comment: Yes, 127/8 points to local machine, but I don't think 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.2:8080 are the same. I can use ssh to set up different tunnels for example on 127.0.0.3:8080 and 127.1.0.1:8080 at the same time without a problem.

Comment: You are able to setup multiple tunnels becaise same ssh service is listening on the port 8080. SSH is doing internal mapping between source ip and destination ip as per you setting. But in other case you are asking operating system to send data coming on port 8080 to two different application.  A port number on a machine uniquely identifies an application.